# Is there a way to stream via UPnP from play.googl.com/music? (Like BubbleUPnP can for Android?)

Tags: google-play-music, streaming

BubbleUPnP is able to login to your Google Music account on your Android device and then stream songs from the service directly to a player via UPnP, be it your home cinema or TV. If Android can do it, a PC should be able to do it too.

Is there a way to do this with your computer?

Let's say a Chrome extension or anything similar?

If not, is there no demand for it?

<sub>While we are at it, would something like that be possible with Pandora service?

This is another question, but if it can be answered with one answer that hits them both I mention it for that purpose here.</sub>